# ruby on rails I need to build an object from api data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, view, controller

I want to create an object from data API. At first, the user will have to enter his immaticulation number. Once registration typed him return the following data in the view show

## vehicles_controller:

```
   @vehicle = Vehicle.new
   @vehicles = []
    vehicle_number = params['immatricule'].capitalize
    vehicles.each do |vehicule|
    data_api = CarRegistrationFrance.Lookup(#{"vehicle_number"},"username","password")

Api_data response:

 => {"Description"=>"RENAULT CLIO IV", "RegistrationYear"=>"2017", "CarMake"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"RENAULT"}, "CarModel"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"CLIO IV"}, "EngineSize"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"4"}, "FuelType"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"DIESEL"}, "MakeDescription"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"RENAULT"}, "ModelDescription"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"CLIO IV"}, "Immobiliser"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>""}, "IndicativeValue"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>0}, "DriverSide"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>""}, "BodyStyle"=>{"CurrentTextValue"=>"BERLINE 5 PORTES"}, "RegistrationDate"=>"2017-10-30","ExtendedData"=>{"anneeSortie"=>"2017", "boiteDeVitesse"=>"", "carburantVersion"=>"D", "carrosserieVersion"=>"", "classeSra"=>"K", "libVersion"=>"1.5 DCI 90 EDITION ONE EDC", "libelleModele"=>"CLIO IV", "marque"=>"RE", "modele"=>"88", "produit"=>"", "puissance"=>"4", "version"=>"", "cleCarrosserie"=>"", "groupeSra"=>"30", "nbPlace"=>"5", "datePremiereMiseCirculation"=>"30102017", "questionBatterie"=>"", "electrique"=>"", "genre"=>"", "typeVehicule"=>"", "numSerieMoteur"=>"VF15RBJ0D58888591", "valeurANeufSRA"=>"", "niveauRisqueVol"=>"", "protectionConstructeur"=>"", "puissanceDyn"=>"", "segmentVeh"=>""}} 
    @vehicles << data_api
    vehicle.description => data_api["Description"]
    vehicle.annee => data_api["RegistrationYear"]


    def vehicle_params
  params.require(:voiture).permit(:immatricule, :description, :annee)
end
```

Once the user enters his registration numbers I want to join

```
data_api ["Description"] << vehicle ["description"]
```

attach the data to the attribute of the vehicle object

```
data_api ["RegistrationYear"] << vehicle ["year"]
```

/user[:id]/vehicle/new its an example

```
<%= form_tag("/vehicle", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:immatricule, "") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:immatricule) %>
  <%= submit_tag("create") %>
```

/user[:id]/vehicle/show it an example

```
<%= @vehicle.api_data["Description"] %>
<%= @vehicle.api_data["RegistrationYear"] %>
```

1. enter your immatricule number
2. post immatricule of vehicle user to api_data
3. create objet vehicle from response api_data
4. render show view

I've tried several operations but I can not find a solution.

Comment: Can you please narrow down your issue? It's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you enter your vehicle registration and the API returns you the information on the vehicle once recovered the answer of the API build the object vehicle of my database with the data api json

Comment: sorry my english is weak

Comment: Can you please share the output of your API, Vehicle object from your database and your expected output(combination of both)?

Answer (score 2):

So this sort of feels like you coming from a background without being `CRUD` (`Create, Read, Update, Delete`) aware ... based on your not listing the controllers etc that you are working to achieve this stuff (crucial to any response to answer your question).

Based on the status of the question 2/22 @ 06:18am -600 here is some quick notes ...

You are going to want to do this walk-thru for getting started - [RailsGuides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Second, I think from your URL you listed - you have a nested route & are using a matching nested model.  The answer changes which controller/action/routing I am suggesting - so make sure to clarify if you aren't before you try to understand this answer ...

*All of these are guess work as there are details of your implementation we are missing (route.rb file, if this is a script you as admin are calling or each user is running the update themselves, if this stuff works at all).*

---

Once finished the question you meant to ask should be ...

"Which controller & controller action should I use to update the registration information?"  (Commonly shown as `controller#action`)

The `CRUD` answer is the `update` (rails calls it `Edit` to display view & `update` to execute).

The reason your question throwing people off is that the Rails Way (`CRUD`) already has basic code for a controller and action for that controller action to update the field.  You shouldn't have to create an object yourself - all data objects that are permanent should be Rails model objects.

In your case `Vehicle` model in the `app/models/vehicle.rb` would be my guess.  You might choose to nest the route for that in the `config/routes.rb` file as ...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :vehicle
  ...
```

Which would give you a route/url of `"/{:user_id}/{:vehicle_id}/{controller action}"`.

This assumes ...

1. A user coming to your application on the web or network
2. They sign up or in
3. Display the info from the API (I'm not sure if your are looking to feed this info back to that API & that is why you need the object - but assuming you are not)
4. After the user#show controller pulls vehicle model pulls the info from the API
5. Your controller will redirect them to the CRUD `read` action (Rails calls this `Show`).  It's also already coded in the controller action for update.

In your case this would likely be ... `User#show`, which would have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :RegistrationYear` and maybe the `:Description` in the `User` model, referring to the fields in the `Vehicle` model you already have working.

---

For the other case ... you are simply wrapping another API which is getting updated and your rails application isn't holding anything ...

You need a user entity or authentication ... maybe you are getting an omni_auth or other security login token from the API you referenced ... so your steps ...

1. Either login in handled or you create/ login the user
2. Your `User#Show` should either have a link to the `Vehicle#Update` or the `User#Show` view should include that form with field with the user & vehicle id's ... which are filled in already as the the controller executed that API query pull all the information & have the two fields to be updated.
3. The submit button should in a normal rails app be a link to another controller#action which would just execute the API's update interface instead of stashing the info into your own db ... though you could easily put that API interface call in the `controller#action` responsible for showing the form.

I suggest you do a standard object file if you are just wrapping the API with your own rails app ...

```
# depending on where you put this you might need to load it yourself
app/lib/other_api_connection.rb  

# rails prefers this format as part of ruby & it's class autoloading
class OtherAPI < CarRegistrationFrance
  attr_accessor :registration, :description


  def initialize(search_immat, user, pass, api_url = {whatever currently})
    ...
    @user = user 
    @pass = pass 
    @record = look_up
    @api_url = api_url 
  end

  def look_up(search_immat)
    ... 
    Lookup("#{search_immat}", @user, @pass)
  end

  def update_api
    begin
      ... {you haven't shown us the update API url} ...
    rescue {some error from api}
      return "{some error message}"
    end
  end
end
```

So ... you have the API handler object now ...

For use you call it in the controller#action ... lets say User#Show, which submit redirects to `User#Update` or `Vehicle#Update`

```
class Vehicle < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def update
    ... 

    # normal stuff probably needs to be deleted if you aren't saving to your application db THEN updating API (aka just wrapping an API - which I'm assuming you are doing since you haven't said otherwise & it's less work).
    # also you could pass the object as a parameter in the submit link - but that's not really CRUD per say
    @user = {whatever user is}
    api = OtherAPI.new(user, pass)

    # you might have to permit this as parameter to pull it out
    @response_code = api.update_api(:RegistrationYear, :Description) # or whole vehicle record if the API requires

    if @response_code == {whatever valid code is from that API documentation}
      format.html { redirect_to @vehicle, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  ... rest of controller actions
end
```

*Note - I suggested making an API interface class/object because you can then call the code from either controller or action & only have to make the changes in one place if the api url is changed etc ... but you might have to `include OtherAPI` at the top of each controller code.*

Answer (score 0):

hello Thanks for your help

i using devise to authentificate user

## my shemas database:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.float "longitude"
t.float "latitude"
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "username"
t.string "avatar_file_name"
t.string "avatar_content_type"
t.bigint "avatar_file_size"
t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true


 end

  create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "immatricule"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "marque"
    t.string "date_circulation"
    t.string "fuel_type"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_vehicles_on_user_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "vehicles", "users"
```

## my model users:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable
         has_many :vehicles
```

## my model vehicles:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

i need this routes:

```
   user_vehicles GET    /users/:user_id/vehicles(.:format)                                                       vehicles#index
                           POST   /users/:user_id/vehicles(.:format)                                                       vehicles#create
          new_user_vehicle GET    /users/:user_id/vehicles/new(.:format)                                                   vehicles#new
         edit_user_vehicle GET    /users/:user_id/vehicles/:id/edit(.:format)                                              vehicles#edit
              user_vehicle GET    /users/:user_id/vehicles/:id(.:format)                                                   vehicles#show
                           PATCH  /users/:user_id/vehicles/:id(.:format)                                                   vehicles#update
                           PUT    /users/:user_id/vehicles/:id(.:format)                                                   vehicles#update
                           DELETE /users/:user_id/vehicles/:id(.:format)                                                   vehicles#destroy
```

but i'm using devise

in my controller i need to build
vehicles with response api i need to save data in my database
from number immatricule
in form new vehicles users enter number_immatricule
"immatricule" = form new vehicles[:immatricule] users
form get data_api

```
def build_vehicle_user_from_api_data
"description" == data_api["description"]
 "marque" == data_api["CarMake"]
"date_circulation" == data_api["RegistrationDate"]
 "fuel_type" == data_api["fuel_type"]
end
```

I'm looking for how to do that in my controller users or vehicles